# Change the theme of a Polymer app at runtime

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have created a demo Polymer-2 application with a central stylesheet module. During a presentation the question arose on whether the style could be made user specific, meaning each user could f.e. select in his options whether she wants the dark or the light theme.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Just an example:
the current version of the Microsoft .NET Core online documentation has a combobox "Theme" on the right side that lets you choose between dark/light:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netcore-1.1#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_

**Update**

The SO pointed to by daKmoR answered most of my question but I cannot accept it as a full duplicate because in my application an important feature is that the theme can be changed at any time by the user and not only at initialization. I will therefore answer myself since I have now extended the solution given in [How to import stylesheet dynamically Polymer 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731227/how-to-import-stylesheet-dynamically-polymer-2-0).

Comment: maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731227/how-to-import-stylesheet-dynamically-polymer-2-0/45746195

Comment: Yes, that helps indeed! I extended it a little bit to also be able to change the theme at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import stylesheet dynamically Polymer 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731227/how-to-import-stylesheet-dynamically-polymer-2-0)

Comment: Well, the possible duplicate question answers most of my question but I want to mention that I asked my question first. So it's not such that I didn't search hard enough before asking ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the themes consist of CSS variable definitions then the theme files would look something like this:

```
<custom-style>
    <style>
        html {
            --background-color: blue;
            --text-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

Now given some UI control in one of the apps components (button, combobox etc.) the user would be able to change the theme at runtime with this helper method (ES6 class syntax):

```
loadTheme(url) {
    //Remove the currently active theme
    let href = this.resolveUrl(this.currentUrl);
    let link = (document.head.querySelector('link[href="' + href + '"][import-href]'));

    if (link)
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

    //Import the new one        
    this.currentUrl = url;
    Polymer.importHref(this.resolveUrl(url));
}
```

`Polymer.importHref` adds a `<link>` statement to the head of the main file. This link must be exchanged when selecting another theme.
The url of the currently active theme is saved in `currentUrl` and this allows to remove the active theme and replace it with a new one.